# Combining date from one column and time from another to datetime dtype with empty cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe with a column that I will call "date", another called "time_arrival" and a third "time_start".
Column "date" is already in datetime format. I now want to convert the other two, which are currently objects.

For "time_arrival" I used the following syntax:

```
df['time_arrival'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['time_arrival'].astype(str))
```

This worked. However, when using it on "time_start", it won't work because this column doesn't always contain values/ has some empty cells. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `errors` parameter to `pd.to_datetime()` to determine what to do with errors. There are three options - raise, coerce or ignore.

```
If ‘raise’, then invalid parsing will raise an exception.
If ‘coerce’, then invalid parsing will be set as NaN.
If ‘ignore’, then invalid parsing will return the input.
```

Is that what you are looking for?

If not, please add the first n rows to your question using `df.head(n).to_dict()`and maybe give an example of what you are expecting as output.